# How to name event types?

Tags: naming, event-programming

[Clean code](http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) recommends to name methods to be a verb, and classes to be a noun.

I am developing an c++ application using [boost::signal](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals.html) as some kind of event framework, and have defined various events, but naming them to make the code cleaner seems to be problematic.

So, how to name event types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Other naming options may include:

**Format 1:**
On[Objectname][DetailedEventName]

Example:

OnMouseClick

OnMouseRightButtonClick

**Format 2:**
On[DetaieldConditionName]

Examples:

OnRecordNotFound

OnCustomerRowNotFound

Other posts related to this:
[StackOverFlow-EventNames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724085/events-naming-convention-and-style)

Comment: Hehe defnitly the better way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Robert C. Martin mentioned that your names have to be meanful and searchable. It should be a verb or a verb phrase. So from my point of view I would allways clarify that this method is a event by building a verb phrase.

Some examples could be:
- SaveEvent()
- RenderEvent()
- CloseEvent()

Whit this format I am allways able to find the Event-Method. I know exactly that this method is a event and I dont need to seach for some points that let me know that this method is a event.